# Как нарисовать шкалу в chartjs по оси Х

Tags: javascript, chart.js

возникла такая дилемма - нужно нарисовать шкалу по оси Х как на макете (при этом сейчас в ticks выводятся значения (цены) и график отрисован, только не хватает шкалы). Шкалу можно нарисовать через ticks или каким-то другим способом? Есть ли вообще такая возможность у сhartjs?

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      display: false,
      drawBorder: false,
    },
    ticks: {
      padding: 8,
      fontSize: 13,
      fontColor: '#212121',
    },
  }],
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      display: false,
      drawBorder: false,
    },
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      min: 0,
      stepSize: 15000,
      maxRotation: 0,
      autoSkip: true,
      padding: 14,
      fontSize: 13,
      fontColor: '#212121',
      callback(value) {
        return `${value.toLocaleString()} руб.`;
      },
    },
  }],
}
```

[image: скриншот макета]